# Cannot Load Backup-database cmdlet in powershell v 3.0

Tags: powershell

I am trying to work around with writing powershell script to backup sql server 2008 R2 database but the example i have searched they require to add backup-sqldatabase cmdlet, but i am unable to see neither SQLPS or backup-sqldatabase cmdlets, I have recently ugraded to powershell v3 and i am running windows server2008 R2 and SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

From http://blog.smu.edu/wis/2012/11/26/sql-server-powershell-module-sqlps/

> Although the SQLPS module is installed along with SQL Server, you do not have to install SQL Server to obtain the module. You simply need to install three stand-alone packages from the Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Feature Pack, available here:
>   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065
>
> Install the following packages in this order:
>
> Microsoft® System CLR Types for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 (SQLSysClrTypes.msi)
>   Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Shared Management Objects (SharedManagementObjects.msi)
>   Microsoft® Windows PowerShell Extensions for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 (PowerShellTools.msi)
>   Be sure to select the appropriate package platform for each, either x86 or x64.
>
> To load the sqlps module in Windows PowerShell:
>
> Import-Module sqlps

Comment: 1 question here is i am using sql server 2008 R2 , but the links give features for sql server 2012

Comment: It _should_ be backwards compatible.

Comment: HI raf, windows server 2008R2 is a virtual server i am using, but i downloaded powershell on my local desktop and for some reason it loads SQLps and backup-sqldatabase

Comment: Good, that is what was meant to happen:)

Comment: You installed the binaries and they gave you `SQLPS` module, that is what was meant to happen..because you did it.